# Having trouble changing a number inside span tags using a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

Edit: Thank you! It works perfectly now. I really appreciate the quick responses!

Relevant jfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PjG84/2/).

I have a list of spans, each with unique ids, that I want to be able to modify using a href or input (either will work). I'm only working on one right now trying to get it to work, but it doesn't seem to be getting anywhere. The relevant html is:

```
    <ul>
    <li>STR <span id="str">0</span></li>
<br>
<input type='button' onClick="abilUp()" value='increase by 1' />
```

And the relevant javascript is:

```
    var statVal = 1;
function abilUp() {
    var aV = +document.getElementById('str');
    aV = aV + statVal;
    console.log("str ="+ aV);
}
```

The button works, and the function is returning an increase in the console, but the actual value within the span isn't changing. I'm pretty sure it's not recognizing 0 as a number, so I've tried using the following:

```
+document.getElementById('str');
Number(document.getElementById('str'));
parseInt(document.getElementById('str'), 10);
```

I've also tried using a variable with innerHTML, and it isn't working. I know it's possible, I just don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

(Edit to fix the parseInt example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you are getting the `element` in variable `aV` not the value. So you have to get the content in that element and perform operation on that.

Try this

```
var statVal = 1;
function abilUp() {
    var aV = document.getElementById('str');
    aV.textContent = (+aV.textContent) + statVal;
    console.log("str ="+ aV.textContent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the actual text of the div by using innerHTML:

```
var statVal = 1;
function abilUp() {
    var aV = +document.getElementById('str').innerHTML;
    aV = aV + statVal;
    document.getElementById('str').innerHTML= aV;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PjG84/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
function abilUp() {
    var aV = document.getElementById('str').innerHTML;
    var aV = parseInt(aV);
    document.getElementById('str').innerHTML = aV+1;
}
```

simple get the number by useing innerHTML, 
then use parseInt to change from string to number 
and return the inner HTML with the number.

here is the Fidder 
http://jsfiddle.net/PjG84/8/